# how to setup multiple apps on different subdomains using docker compose and 'SteveLTN/https-portal'?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dns, lets-encrypt

I am using DigitalOcean's droplet to host the apps.

I have different apps that I want to run on different subdomains (sub1.example.com,sub2.example.com, etc).

So far I managed to run just one of them on the main domain (eg: example.com)

The folder structure looks like this:

```
-/apps
   -/app1Folder
     docker-compose.yml
     Dockerfile
     -/codeFolder

   -/app2Folder
     docker-compose.yml
     Dockerfile
     -/codeFolder
```

Each Dockerfile looks like this (ofc the appname and 5001 port is different for each app):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["App1.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./App1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "App1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "App1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5001
EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App1.dll"]
```

Each docker-compose.yml file has the following structure:

```
version: '1'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context:  ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1
    ports:
      - '80:80' 
      - '443:443'
    links:
      - app
    restart: always
    environment:
      DOMAINS: 'sub1.example.com -> http://app:5001' 
               # for app2 we route to 'sub2.example.com'
      # STAGE: 'production'
```

From what I understood so far, I should have only one docker-compose file that should contain all my configs for both apps that i need to run.

I am not sure how to make the routing work or what should i change to make it work.

I am new to all this and don't exactly know where should i start.

Right now after i ran the first app, and it is working, I get the **bellow error** when trying to 'docker-compose up' the second one.

I think it has something to do with the fact that I am basically trying to run 2 docker images of https-portal that both expose ports 80 and 443 by default. Even if I change the ports on the second app (app2) it still gives the same error.

I am positive that the DNS is configured corectly and propagated to the host.

**Any suggestion is welcomed! Please 'halp'! :)**

```
Signing certificates from https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory ...
https-portal_1  | Parsing account key...
https-portal_1  | Parsing CSR...
https-portal_1  | Found domains: sub2.example.com
https-portal_1  | Getting directory...
https-portal_1  | Directory found!
https-portal_1  | Registering account...
https-portal_1  | Already registered!
https-portal_1  | Creating new order...
https-portal_1  | Order created!
https-portal_1  | Verifying sub2.example.com...
https-portal_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
https-portal_1  |   File "/bin/acme_tiny", line 198, in <module>
https-portal_1  |     main(sys.argv[1:])
https-portal_1  |   File "/bin/acme_tiny", line 194, in main
https-portal_1  |     signed_crt = get_crt(args.account_key, args.csr, args.acme_dir, log=LOGGER, CA=args.ca, disable_check=args.disable_check, directory_url=args.directory_url, contact=args.contact)
https-portal_1  |   File "/bin/acme_tiny", line 149, in get_crt
https-portal_1  |     raise ValueError("Challenge did not pass for {0}: {1}".format(domain, authorization))
https-portal_1  | ValueError: Challenge did not pass for sub2.example.com: {u'status': u'invalid', u'challenges': [{u'status': u'invalid', u'validationRecord': [{u'url': u'http://sub2.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/neHJEUpiAjxhvk1nicoRnDaT_xOAIXMaG8MxJstPy14', u'hostname': u'sub2.example.com', u'addressUsed': u'143.198.249.45', u'port': u'80', u'addressesResolved': [u'IP_ADDRESS']}], u'url': u'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/4917620723/B0GD9Q', u'token': u'neHJEUpiAjxhvk1nicoRnDaT_xOAIXMaG8MxJstPy14', u'error': {u'status': 400, u'type': u'urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection', u'detail': u'143.198.249.45: Fetching http://sub2.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/neHJEUpiAjxhvk1nicoRnDaT_xOAIXMaG8MxJstPy14: Error getting validation data'}, u'validated': u'2023-01-11T19:31:34Z', u'type': u'http-01'}], u'identifier': {u'type': u'dns', u'value': u'sub2.example.com'}, u'expires': u'2023-01-18T19:31:33Z'}
https-portal_1  | ================================================================================
https-portal_1  | Failed to sign sub2.example.com.
https-portal_1  | Make sure you DNS is configured correctly and is propagated to this host 
https-portal_1  | machine. Sometimes that takes a while.
https-portal_1  | ================================================================================
https-portal_1  | Failed to obtain certs for sub2.example.com
https-portal_1  | [cont-init.d] 20-setup: exited 1.
https-portal_1  | [cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
```

Comment: Make one docker compose for both your apps and nginx, and provide the new compose file and nginx conf. You can use other tools, but according to your post, seems like this is your stack